# Docker copy file to host, after entrypoint execution

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a docker file, that creates an image of my automation project that runs maven to execute some tests, how can I copy something from docker back to host AFTER those tests were executed ? Simply adding copy command in Dockerfile, after ENTRYPOINT will start copying straight after executing first command from entrypoint command.

***Dockerfile:***

```
ADD src /usr/src/app/src/
ADD features /usr/src/app/features/
ADD Config.properties /usr/src/app/

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh"]
```

***mvn-entrypoint.sh***

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "PLEASE WAIT..."
sleep 10
echo "STARTING AUTOMATION TESTING"
mvn verify -q -D browser=chrome
exec "$@"
```

Comment: Read up on docker volumes and bind mounts.

Comment: If the main goal of your task is to create files on the host system, it's a bad match for Docker.

Comment: I am running automation testing in docker, once test is executed, it generates test report, now I have another docker image, that runs some simple web server that could hosts this test report, but to do it, first i need to copy test report from container that ran tests back to host, so it can be latter used to build and run another container that runs web server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use docker volume.

Run your container with `docker run -v host/path:/temp imageID cp mvnOutputPath /temp`

`cp mvnOutputPath /temp` is the docker command CMD, executed by `exec "$@"` in your entrypoint